# Arbitrariness of Quantum Heat Current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, electric-current, open-quantum-systems

Given a Hamiltonian $H$ for a closed quantum system, we know that the spectrum is invariant under any constant shift in energy $H'=H+c$. However, when talking about open quantum system where the system is connected to a couple of thermal baths at its boundaries, it seems that the *heat* current (not particle current) $J$ is not invariant under this shift, as $J\propto\epsilon$ where $\epsilon_k$ are the eigenenergies. Specifically, I am talking about the Lindblad formalism here,
$$ J=\mathrm{Tr}(H\mathcal L_\mathrm{hot} \rho),$$
where $\rho$ is the steady-state density matrix and $\mathcal{L}$ are the superoperator describing one of the heat bath (e.g. the hot bath). In this way $J$ can even become negative (heat flowing to the hot bath and violating the 2nd law), depending on the shift $c$ in the spectrum of the Hamiltonian. What is the source of the arbitrariness of heat current here and how to tackle this problem? What can be said for systems with unbounded spectrum (in thermodynamic limit, $N\to\infty$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heat current as you have defined it is invariant under this shift, otherwise the definition would not make much sense. $J$ does not depend on single eigenenergies $\epsilon_k$, but only on differences of eigenenergies. This can be seen easily:
$$ J' = tr[ H' \mathcal L_{hot} \rho ] = tr[ H \mathcal L_{hot} \rho ] + c\, tr[ \mathcal L_{hot} \rho ] = tr[ H \mathcal L_{hot} \rho ] = J $$
(using $tr[\mathcal L_{hot} \rho] = 0$).

Note that the steady state is invariant as well, since $\mathcal L \rho = \mathcal L' \rho$ for all operators $\rho$. Here, I used the notation $\mathcal L \rho = -i [H, \rho] + \sum_\mu \mathcal L_\mu \rho$ and $\mathcal L_\mu$ is the dissipator corresponding to the $\mu$-th environment. (The $\mathcal L_\mu$ typically depend on the differences of eigenenergies of $H$, but they will never change under a shift $H \to H + c$. Since $[H, \rho] = [H', \rho]$, we obtain $\mathcal L = \mathcal L'$.)

Comment: $tr{L\rho}=0$ is only if you consider the full Liouvillian, $d\rho/dt = L\rho$, since current is defined in steady state. I'm talking about heat entering one of the thermal baths here, suppose $L\rho= L_1\rho+L_2\rho$, for hot and cold baths.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes trace is cyclic so $tr L\rho=0$. But here comes another problem, for $H'$ the steady might be different, $\rho'$, so that $J$ is still not covariant

Comment: @donnydm I edited the post.

Comment: nonequilibrium systems don't relax into Gibbs state

Comment: @donnydm Invariance of the Gibbs state illustrates the greater point, namely that all physical quantities are invariant under an energy shift... but fair enough, I edited again.